# Folder size on Artifactory

Tags: api, artifactory

Is there a way to find out the size of a folder inside the Artifactory repository via the API? This is not in the official documentation on the jfrog website.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no straightforward approach but you can use the [File List REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileList) to get the size of all artifacts in that specific folder as below,

> curl -uadmin -XGET
> https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/storage/repo-name/folder1/folder2?list&deep=1&listFolders=0&mdTimestamps=1

The output will have the size of each file and therefore adding up all the files sizes will have the actual folder size